# decoding comparing list to dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to compare to see if a word in a list is in a dictionary full or words.  I'm writing a program that decode a txt file.

Say here is one the the lines:

```
['Now', 'we', 'are', 'engaged', 'in', 'a', 'great', 'civil', 'war,']
```

I want to go the the dictionary and check to see if any of these words are in there.  If so, I'll put the strings together and write to a file.  All I want to know is how to compare the two.  I'd first lowercase the first word in the list since all words are lowercase.

an example of my dictionary would be:

```
{"now": "", "help": "", "you": ""}
```

but filled with MANY more words.

If you want to see my overall code just ask :)

Here is my code for making the dictionary.  Each line is a word.

```
f = open('dictionary.txt', "r")
dictionary = {}
for line in f:
    word = line.strip()
    dictionary[word] = ""
print dictionary
```

*updated*

```
def CaeserCipher(string, k):
    #setting up variables to move through
    upper = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'*10000
    lower = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'*10000

    newCipher = ''

    #looping each letter and moving it k times
    for letter in string:
        if letter in upper:
            if upper.index(letter) + k > 25:
                indexPosition = (upper.index(letter) + k) 
                newCipher = newCipher + upper[indexPosition]
            else:
                indexPosition = upper.index(letter) + k
                newCipher = newCipher + upper[indexPosition]
        elif letter in lower:
            if lower.index(letter) + k > 25:

                indexPosition = (lower.index(letter) + k)  
                newCipher = newCipher + lower[indexPosition]
            else:
                indexPosition = lower.index(letter) + k
                newCipher = newCipher + lower[indexPosition]
        else:
            newCipher = newCipher + letter


    return newCipher

f = open('dictionary.txt', "r")
dictionary = set()
for line in f:
    word = line.strip()
    dictionary.add(word)
print dictionary

#main file
#reading file and encrypting text

f = open('encrypted.txt')
string = ''
out = open("plain1.txt", "w")
#working through each line
for line in f:
    for k in range(26):

        line = [CaeserCipher(word, k) for word in line]
        print line


        #listSplit = re.split('[,\[\]]', line)
        #print listSplit
        string = ("".join(line))
        listOfWords = string.split()
        lowercase_line = [word.lower() for word in listOfWords]
        out.write(dictionary.intersection(lowercase_line))  


f.close()
out.close()
```

Comment: Will the values of the dictionary always be empty strings? If so, have you considered using a set instead?

Comment: is there a more efficient way of doing that instead of "" keys? @Kevin

Comment: Are you asking how to construct the set initially? Well, you'd have `dictionary = set()` instead of `dictionary = {}`, and `dictionary.add(word)` instead of `dictionary[word] = ""`

Comment: I'll add all my code so you can get a better understanding. @Kevin

Comment: Is that your up to date code? `out.write(x` doesn't look valid to me.

Comment: @kevin, my bad let me add what you had

Comment: They never teach you about python `set`s in introductory courses in Python... but they're so useful.

Comment: @2rsts where would i go from here though?

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to represent your dictionary as a set, you can use `intersection` to find all the words in the dictionary that exist in the line.

```
dictionary = {"now", "help", "you"}
line = ['Now', 'we', 'are', 'engaged', 'in', 'a', 'great', 'civil', 'war,']
lowercase_line = [word.lower() for word in line]
#todo: also filter out punctuation, so "war," becomes "war"
print dictionary.intersection(lowercase_line)
```

result:

```
set(['now'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if any(word.lower() in your_word_dict for word in line_list):
   ' '.join(line_list)
   # write to file
```

check to see if any of the words in your word list are in your dictionary and if they are join them into a string and write them to a file